# How to enlarge the SVG icon in Material UI iconButtons?

Tags: css, svg, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Has anyone built webpages using [react.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and the [Material UI](https://www.material-ui.com/) library? How should I resize the icon size? It is a SVG icon.
I just built a "create new" component, which is a piece of material paper with a content add button on the top. Here is the code.

```js
import React from 'react';
import Paper from 'material-ui/lib/paper';
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/content/add';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/lib/icon-button';


const styleForPaper = {
  width: '96vw',
  height: '20vh',
  margin: 20,
  textAlign: 'center',
  display: 'inline-block',
};

const styleForButton = {
  'marginTop': '7vh',
};


const PaperToAddNewWidgets = () => (
  <div>

    <Paper style={styleForPaper} zDepth={2}>

    <IconButton
        style={styleForButton}
        touch={true}
        tooltip="Add New Widget">

    <ContentAdd/>

    </IconButton>

    </Paper>
  </div>
);

export default PaperToAddNewWidgets;
```

It looks OK (make sure you are viewing it at full size), but the icon is too small. Then I opened the chrome dev tool, and saw the following html code.

```html
<div style="background-color:#ffffff;transition:all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);box-shadow:0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.16),
         0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);border-radius:2px;width:96vw;height:20vh;margin:20px;text-align:center;display:inline-block;mui-prepared:;" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0"><button style="border:10px;background:none;box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;font:inherit;font-family:Roboto, sans-serif;tap-highlight-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);cursor:pointer;text-decoration:none;outline:none;transform:translate3d(0, 0, 0);position:relative;transition:all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;padding:12px;width:48px;height:48px;font-size:0;margin-top:7vh;mui-prepared:;-webkit-appearance:button;" tabindex="0" type="button" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.0"><div data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.0.0"><span style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;overflow:hidden;mui-prepared:;" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.0.0.0"></span><div style="position: absolute; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 32px; padding: 0px 16px; z-index: 3000; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden; top: -10000px; border-radius: 2px; opacity: 0; left: -44px; transition: top 0ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 450ms, transform 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms, opacity 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-user-select: none;" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.0.0.1:0"><div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 0px; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); border-radius: 50%; transition: width 0ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 450ms, height 0ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 450ms, backgroundColor 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms; width: 0px; height: 0px; background-color: transparent;" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.0.0.1:0.0"></div><span style="position:relative;white-space:nowrap;mui-prepared:;" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.0.0.1:0.1">Add New Widget</span></div><svg style="display:inline-block;height:24px;width:24px;transition:all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1) 0ms;fill:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);mui-prepared:;-webkit-user-select:none;" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.0.0.1:2:$/=10"><path d="M19 13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z" data-reactid=".0.2.0.1.0.0.0.1:2:$/=10.0"></path></svg></div></button></div>
```

Using chrome dev tool, I revised the svg icon size and the viewbox property of svg and made the icon larger in browser. But I am not sure how I can resize the icon size in my code. If I write a CSS file to revise the svg it will be problematic if there are more than one svg elements.

Comment: If you're using `<i class="material-icons">&#abc;</i>`, then it is simply updating the NN of `font-size: NNpx` eg: in jQuery `$(".material-icons").css('font-size', "48px");`

Comment: Alvin, thank you for your insights. 
"font-size" works for "<i class="material-icons">&#abc;</i>", but does not solve my problems. 
I used the     <ContentAdd/> from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/content/add', which is generates svg icons on webpage.

Comment: My bad, to increase SVG Icons, you need to adjust the `style={}` of `<svg style="display:inline-block;height:24px;width:24px;...`, eg: try changing `height:48px; width:48px`. There are some icons which are FONT base, for that it is `font-size` tweak

Comment: just to clarify, `material-ui` (in react) isn't based on `material design lite`. if you're looking for MDL, check out the `react-mdl` library

Comment: Thanks, @Brandon. I will update the question after I get the privilege to edit questions.

Comment: Use inspect option to track the classname & use your desired style,
After each style override use !important to overwrite

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Note**: iconStyle prop is no longer supported on IconButton Material UI making this answer obsolete

You have to set the size of the icon in the `iconStyle` prop in `<IconButton>`.  Example below [from the material-ui docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button).

From my experience, if you set just the height or the width, nothing happens--only seems to work when you set height & width to the same value.

```
import React from 'react';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import ActionHome from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/home';

const styles = {

  largeIcon: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
  },

};

const IconButtonExampleSize = () => (
  <div>
    <IconButton
      iconStyle={styles.largeIcon}

    >
      <ActionHome />
    </IconButton>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Wow, tried to set the Icon's style itself, had no clue it worked this way. Who designed that? sigh.

Comment: It appears that the `iconStyle` prop is no longer supported by `material-ui`. That makes this accepted answer incorrect.

Answer (score 80):

do  this

```
<SomeIcon className="svg_icons"/>

.svg_icons {
  transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

just use scale :D it works

Comment: problem is the width doesn't grow with it causing overlap

Comment: The scale() method increases or decreases the size of an element (according to the parameters given for the width and height).

The following example increases the <div> element to be two times of its original width, and three times of its original height:   
```
div {
  transform: scale(2, 3);
}
```

Comment: This won't always work because it doesn't scale the container of the icon. If you use a large scale factor, you can end up with a huge icon in a tiny box, which make it overlap everything around!

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Also works for flipping icons and using the [sx prop](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/): `<Button startIcon={<ExpandCircleDownIcon `**`sx={{ transform: "scaleY(-1)" }}`**` />}>`

Answer (score 32):

No. Most of the other answers are unsatisfactory and are poor practice, at least in 2021. This answer is literally answered in the [documentation here](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/) and doesn't require any CSS hacks to get working.

In MUI, the `Button` and `IconButton` components are just essentially wrappers that nest the child `Icon` element in an `<a>` or `<Link>` (react-router) element. They don't have any intrinsic control over the size. Thus, to increase the button size, just increase the size of the `Icon` child of `IconButton` using the `fontSize` property. This will automatically make the button larger.

For instance, to make the `IconButton` below larger:

```
<IconButton>
  <Icon />
</IconButton>
```

We just increase the size of the `Icon` child directly.

```
<IconButton>
  <Icon fontSize="large" />
</IconButton>
```

However, this is largest size you can specify with the `fontSize` property. To go even larger, we must configure the CSS `font-size` property manually.

```
<IconButton>
  <Icon style={{ fontSize: 60 }} />
</IconButton>
```

Simple as.

EDIT: Apparently, for whatever reason, `Button` components have a `size` property that allows their size to be controlled, but `IconButton` components don't. I'm not sure why MUI is so inconsistent...

Answer (score 22):

I faced the same issue while using the last React version (which is today v16.13.1) and Material-ui (which is today v4.9.14).

## How I solved it?

By simply adding this style to the icon button

```
MyIconButton: {
    '& svg': {
      fontSize: theSizeIWant
    }
}
```

## Complete example

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  deleteIcon1: {
    '& svg': {
      fontSize: 25
    }
  },
  deleteIcon2: {
    '& svg': {
      fontSize: 50
    }
  },
  deleteIcon3: {
    '& svg': {
      fontSize: 75
    }
  },
  deleteIcon4: {
    '& svg': {
      fontSize: 100
    }
  }
}));


export default function App() {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">

      <h1>fontSize: 25</h1>
      <IconButton className={classes.deleteIcon1}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>

      <h1>fontSize: 50</h1>
      <IconButton className={classes.deleteIcon2}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>

      <h1>fontSize: 75</h1>
      <IconButton className={classes.deleteIcon3}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>

      <h1>fontSize: 100</h1>
      <IconButton className={classes.deleteIcon4}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>

    </div>
  );
}
```

and the result will be:

[image]

## Live running code

I created [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-resize-iconbutton-vgb74?file=/src/App.js).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Very useful when I need to change the default action buttons size in my Material React Table since I can only apply css sx to the IconButton component but not the svg child.

Answer (score 11):

With the latest version of material-ui (3.1.0), you can change padding of IconButton and fontSize of SvgIcon to update the looks.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  smallButton: {
    padding: 6
  },
  largeButton: {
    padding: 24
  },
  largeIcon: {
    fontSize: "3em"
  },
  input: {
    display: "none"
  }
});    

function IconButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton className={classes.smallButton} aria-label="Delete">
        <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
        <DeleteIcon fontSize="large" />
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton className={classes.largeButton} aria-label="Delete">
        <DeleteIcon className={classes.largeIcon} />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/o9rjmv9886)

Answer (score 6):

For the current version of MUI (v5.8.5) there is a `fontSize` prop on the icons with different set sizes of 'small', 'medium', 'large' so you could do something like:

```
<HomeIcon fontSize="small" />
```

If one of those set sizes doesn't fit your needs there is also the option to use 'inherit' if you'd like it to match the font size of the container it is in and not have its own separate size.

Lastly, you could use the `sx` property which MUI places on all its components and in there it will accept the `fontSize` property which allows you to set the size directly to the icon. For instance:

```
<WhatshotIcon sx={{ fontSize: 140 }} />
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/icons/#size

Answer (score 4):

You could just use the fontSize attribute on the child node of IconButton element, that is, in your case - ContentAdd node.

```
<IconButton
        style={styleForButton}
        touch={true}
        tooltip="Add New Widget">

    <ContentAdd fontSize="large" />

</IconButton>
```

There are 4 options available - inherit, default, small and large.

Source - https://material-ui.com/api/icon/#props

Answer (score 3):

When you need that for your global project you might add a new variant to your MUI theme.

```
components: {
   MuiSvgIcon: {
      variants: [
        {
          props: { fontSize: 'huge' },
          style: {
            fontSize: '5rem',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
}
```

In order to get it worked for TS, you might need to extend the module declarations:

```
declare module '@mui/material/SvgIcon' {
  interface SvgIconPropsSizeOverrides {
    huge: true;
  }
}
```

usage:

```
<HomeIcon fontSize="huge" />
```

I also wrote a little post on [dev.to](https://dev.to/karladler/extend-svgicon-sizes-in-react-material-ui-44f8)

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me
fontSize="large"

```
<Badge badgeContent={4} color="primary" >
       <CameraAltIcon  fontSize="large"   />
</Badge>
```

look Props --> fontSize

https://material-ui.com/api/icon/

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue I've encountered so many times when using svgs in React, especially when using custom SVGs. it annoyed me enough so I've written a wrapper that can scale a given SVG React element to a specified size.

I've published it as a package: [react-svg-resizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg-resizer)
. this is a simple wrapper that can scale any SVG element(including MUI-icons).

[here's codesandbox with demo with examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-svg-resizer-demo-c2s7n3?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
import YourIcon from "@mui/icons-material/YourIcon";


<SvgResizer size={50}>
  <YourIcon />
</SvgResizer>
```

The Icon can be any SVG element. a custom one, or MUI Icon.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of enlarging the svg, one is to [override the style with iconStyle](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-button), the other is to edit the code found in https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/SvgIcon/SvgIcon.js

Note: `ContentAdd` imports from `SvgIcon`

```
const mergedStyles = Object.assign({
 ..
  height: 24, // <-- change default height
  width: 24,  // <-- change default width
 ..
}, style);

return (
  <svg
    {...other}
   ..
    style={prepareStyles(mergedStyles)}
   ..
  >
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using IconStyle prop to change the size of svg icon.

```
<IconButton 
   tooltip="Add New Group" 
   tooltipPosition="top-center" 
   style={{padding: 0, height: 0}} 
   iconStyle={{height: 31, width: 48}} 
   onClick={e => this.openNewList()} 
   disabled={!this.state.newAvailable}>

  <ActionHome />

</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is always simple things to do

> give an classname to your material ui icon
> And go to your css file and give

```
height:40px !important and width 40px !impoetant
```

Answer (score 1):

If className={ classes.classname } , fontSize : '40px' , size= 'large' etc not working then try it inline styling, you can give your height and width size as per required

```
<OpenInNewIcon style={{ height: '18px', width: '18px' }} />
```

I hope it will work,

Answer (score 1):

Resize using

1. `fontSize`

   ```js
   <Box sx={{ fontSize: '2rem' }}>
      <CloseIcon sx={{ fill: 'white', fontSize: 'inherit', mt: 0.375 }} />
   </Box>
   ```
2. `width` or`height`

   ```js
   <Box sx={{ width: '15vw' }}>
      <CloseIcon sx={{ fill: 'white', width: '100%', height: '100%', mt: 0.375 }} />
   </Box>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you using Sass:

```
.divWithTargetSVG {
  .MuiSvgIcon-root {
    font-size: Xrem/px; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem with the SVG icon size. I also needed to be smaller when I hit the 768 media query break point.

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { TextField, IconButton } from '@material-ui/core';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

const StyledCloseIcon = withStyles(theme => ({
root: {
    fontSize: 35,
    [theme.breakpoints.down('768')]: {
         fontSize: 19,
    }
 },
}))(CloseIcon);
```

use it here like this:

```
<StyledTextField
  size='small'
  fullWidth
  id="standard-bare"
  variant="outlined"
  InputProps={{ endAdornment: (<IconButton size='small'><StyledCloseIcon /></IconButton>), }} />
```

Hope it helps someone. Cheers!