# want to increase previous and next page pagination icon size in material react table

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I want to increase `<` previous page and `>` next page icon size in material table react
code is as follows::

```
localization = 
  { { body   : {} 
    , toolbar: { searchTooltip: 'Search'} 
    , pagination: 
      { labelRowsSelect   : 'rows'
      , labelDisplayedRows: ' {from}-{to} of {count}'
      , firstTooltip      : 'First Page'
      , previousTooltip   : 'Previous Page'
      , nextTooltip       : 'Next Page'
      , previousLabel     : '<'
      , nextLabel         : '>'
      , size              : "lg"
      , lastTooltip       : 'Last Page'
  } } }
```

Comment: which npm are you using ???

Comment: just find these label's classes or tags and override size with font-size or any property regarding size with !important tag

Comment: are you using react-material-table ??

Comment: yes using material table

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482126/how-to-enlarge-the-svg-icon-in-material-ui-iconbuttons).

Material-UI [TablePagination](https://material-ui.com/api/table-pagination/) Component allows you to pass an ActionsComponent prop (they provide their own default TablePaginationActions component if you don't pass it yourself).

In your custom ActionsComponent you are able to define the IconButton component styles with `iconStyle` prop.

Here is an example of a custom ActionsComponent from [Material-UI docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/):

```
function TablePaginationActions(props) {

  const handleFirstPageButtonClick = event => {
    onChangePage(event, 0);
  };

  const handleBackButtonClick = event => {
    onChangePage(event, page - 1);
  };

  const handleNextButtonClick = event => {
    onChangePage(event, page + 1);
  };

  const handleLastPageButtonClick = event => {
    onChangePage(event, Math.max(0, Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1));
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <IconButton
        onClick={handleFirstPageButtonClick}
        disabled={page === 0}
        aria-label="first page"
      >
        {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <LastPageIcon /> : <FirstPageIcon />}
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton onClick={handleBackButtonClick} disabled={page === 0} aria-label="previous page">
        {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowRight /> : <KeyboardArrowLeft />}
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton
        onClick={handleNextButtonClick}
        disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
        aria-label="next page"
      >
        {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <KeyboardArrowLeft /> : <KeyboardArrowRight />}
      </IconButton>
      <IconButton
        onClick={handleLastPageButtonClick}
        disabled={page >= Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) - 1}
        aria-label="last page"
      >
        {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? <FirstPageIcon /> : <LastPageIcon />}
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```